# How to parse json with Alamofire in Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I'm new in iOS programming language and I'm trying to fetch data from a WordPress JSON into a table view. I'm encountering the error:

> value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

when I try to instantiate the object of the array.

Here is the JSON:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1352,
    "date": "2019-10-16T09:30:39",
    "date_gmt": "2019-10-16T09:30:39",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/ddjhgtr/"
    },
    "modified": "2019-10-16T13:23:41",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-10-16T13:23:41",
    "slug": "ddjhgtr",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/ddjhgtr/",
    "title": "ddjhgtr",
    "content": "eryyreytyvggjggvhghhh",
    "excerpt": "eryyreyty",
    "author": 2,
    "featured_media": {
        "id": 1418,
        "url": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/10-62.jpeg"
    },
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Uncategorized",
            "description": ""
        }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1352"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/users/2"
            }
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1352"
            }
        ],
        "version-history": [
            {
                "count": 3,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1352/revisions"
            }
        ],
        "predecessor-version": [
            {
                "id": 1419,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1352/revisions/1419"
            }
        ],
        "wp:featuredmedia": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1418"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=1352"
            }
        ],
        "wp:term": [
            {
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=1352"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "post_tag",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=1352"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "difficulty-level-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/difficulty-level-course?post=1352"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "category-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/category-course?post=1352"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "location-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/location-course?post=1352"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "duration-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/duration-course?post=1352"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
 },
```

....(many other News objects)

```
{
    "id": 774,
    "date": "2019-10-07T07:30:51",
    "date_gmt": "2019-10-07T07:30:51",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/name-here/"
    },
    "modified": "2019-10-07T07:30:51",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-10-07T07:30:51",
    "slug": "name-here",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/name-here/",
    "title": "name here",
    "content": "desc here",
    "excerpt": "desc here",
    "author": 2,
    "featured_media": null,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Uncategorized",
            "description": ""
        }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/774"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/users/2"
            }
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=774"
            }
        ],
        "version-history": [
            {
                "count": 0,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/774/revisions"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=774"
            }
        ],
        "wp:term": [
            {
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=774"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "post_tag",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=774"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "difficulty-level-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/difficulty-level-course?post=774"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "category-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/category-course?post=774"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "location-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/location-course?post=774"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "duration-course",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://wepress.comm-it.it/wp-json/wp/v2/duration-course?post=774"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
      }
  }
]
```

For the moment I'm interested to get just the image (`featured_media`), title and content of these "objects" and put them into the `tableView`. Indeed here are the structs that I created for them:

The news represents the struct contained into the JSON array

```swift
struct News {
    public var id: Int
    public var title: String
    public var content: String
    public var image: FeaturedMedia
}
```

```swift
struct FeaturedMedia {
    public var id: Int
    public var url: String
}
```

Here is the `UITableViewCell` class:

```swift
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var newsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var newsContent: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

And here the `UITableViewController` class:

```swift
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Alamofire_SwiftyJSON
import SwiftyJSON

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var newsList: [News] = [News]()

    func parseJsonNews() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Alamofire.request("link request", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let news = [value]
                    print(news) // here in console it prints correctly the json, starting with [<__NSArrayI 0x6000001a9e60 ....
                    for new in news {
                        let title = new["title"]
                        print(title)
                    }
                    print(newsss)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case.failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseJsonNews()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.newsList.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsCell", for: indexPath) as? NewsTableViewCell


        // Configure the cell...
        let imageUrl = URL.init(string: newsList[indexPath.row].featuredMedia.url)
        cell?.newsTitle.text = self.newsList[indexPath.row].title
        cell?.newsContent.text = self.newsList[indexPath.row].content
        cell.newsImage.load(url: imageUrl!)
        return cell!
    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking for a solution, I just found many ways to parse dictionary JSON, but in this case, it is an array so I modified the code as you read at `parseJsonNews` method but it doesn't work properly.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: May be this will works for you -> https://medium.com/better-programming/json-parsing-in-swift-2498099b78f

Comment: is this line print anything? `print(title)`

Comment: What line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: You need to use JsonDecoder to parse the values in the response. The struct that you have taken should be made Codable and then you can use JSONDecoder to decode them into your model class. Let me know if you want help with the code for JSONDecoder.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed no it doesn't print anything

Comment: @EmreCiftci Thank you, I'll study it!

Comment: @Swati I changed way from Alamofire to Codable and it seems to work! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can decode with `Codable` like this:

```
let data = try? JSONDecoder().decode([DummyData].self, from: jsonData)
```

But first, all of your models must comform `Codable` protocol. For example:

```
struct DummyData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let date, dateGmt: String
    let modified, modifiedGmt, slug, status: String
    let type: String
    let link: String
    let title, content, excerpt: String
    let author: Int
    let commentStatus, pingStatus: String
    let sticky: Bool
    let template, format: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, date
        case dateGmt = "date_gmt"
        case modified
        case modifiedGmt = "modified_gmt"
        case slug, status, type, link, title, content, excerpt, author
        case commentStatus = "comment_status"
        case pingStatus = "ping_status"
        case sticky, template, format
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it is working! But when I start the simulator, it set the table view correctly, but when I scroll the tableView the rows changes their hight becoming bigger

Comment: It sounds like Auto Layout problem. I can't help because I don't know the details, but Apple has a very good documentation about Auto Layout. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: Also you can change height of all cells in `heightForRowAt` function of `UITableViewDelegate`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. The error `value of type 'Any' has no subscripts`, refers to your line `let title = new["title"]`.
   the response results from `Alamofire` in the `.success` enum returns a type of `Any`,
   this is true to the whole array of data that you fetched.
   The `Any` type in swift doesn't have any `subscripts` implementations (i.e: you cannot access vars inside it using the following syntax `obj['MY_VAR_NAME']`.
2. In order to access the `title` from your `news` object like so `let title = new["title"]`, you have to first cast the objects to a dictionary, this could be done like this:

   ```
           // ... 
           let news = [value]
           print(news)
           for new in news {
               if let obj = new as? [String: Any] {
                   let title = obj["title"]
                   print(title)
               }
           }
           // ...
   ```
3. In order to parse/use your custom structs, they must first comply to swift's `Codable` protocol.

   ```
    /// Example show only News, but the same which be used for FeaturedMedia
     struct News {
       public var id: Int
       public var title: String
       public var content: String
       public var image: FeaturedMedia?
       init?(jsonString: String) {
          guard let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
                return nil
          }
          guard let object = News(data: data) else {
                   return nil
          }
          self = object
      }

      init?(data: Data) {
          guard let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from:  
           data) else {
                 return nil
          }
         self = object
     }
     // Optional, for custom key names (i.e: "image" instead of "featured_media"
     private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "id"
            case image = "featured_media"
          // etc..
     }

   }
   ```

After you've done number 4, you can then init your objects like so:

```
            // ... 
            let news = [value]
            print(news)
            for new in news {
                if let obj = News(new) {
                  /// obj is now a News object
                    let title = obj.title
                    print(title)
                }
            }
            // ...
```

if you are in pursuit for even more info (for example to init the whole array)
check out [this](https://dev.to/jaumevn/parsing-json-with-swift-5-2m40)
I hope I've cleared things up:)

Answer (score -1):

```
 func ComplainData() {
     let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
     var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Constant.localBaseurl2 + "compID") !, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
     request.httpMethod = "GET"
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
         data,
         response,
         error in
         if let response = response {
             let nsHTTPResponse = response as!HTTPURLResponse
             print(nsHTTPResponse)
         }

         if let error = error {
             print("\(error)")
             return
         }

         if let data = data {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                 decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase //or any other Decoder\

                 do {
                     let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                     let memberRecord =
                         try jsonDecoder.decode(COMPLAINTSVC.GetComplaints.self, from: data)
                     print(memberRecord.message)

                     for detailData in memberRecord.message {
                         print(detailData)
                     }
                 } catch {
                     print(error.localizedDescription)
                 }
             }
         }
         semaphore.signal()
     }
     task.resume()
     semaphore.wait()
 }
```

Comment: `How to parse json with Alamofire` There's no usage of Alamofire in your answer, this is off-topic.